# Instagram giving too much data

Tags: php, regex, filtering, instagram, hashtag

I'm trying to pull in all Instagram images for a specific tag, using this endpoint

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag}/media/recent
```

The problem I'm having is that I want it to give me back just images with the hashtag in the caption. What it does give me are images with the hashtag in both the caption and people who have added that hashtag via a comment on other images.

This is what it gives me

```
data {  
    caption : {  
        text : "#notthehashtagIwant'
    }

    comment : {
        data : {
            text : "#hashtagIWant'
        }
    }

}
```

How do I, via regex or anything else, manage to get just the images with the hashtag thats in the caption? Also how do I then manage to get a constant amount of images if I do have to filter down like that?

Comment: That almost looks like JSON. Just grab the bit you want and ignore the rest?

Comment: Never seen JSON open with a `"` and close with a `'`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `json_decode()` and work with it that way: [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/json_decode) entry.  Then you could loop over the data and grab what you wanted.

You did not mention which PHP Instagram API you were using.  This one looks like it may have more methods that would be conducive to what you are trying to accomplish: [Instagram PHP API V2 by cosenary](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API)